# getimagesize() handle spaces in local path?

Tags: php, image

I'm not sure how I could make getimagesize() handle spaces for a local path.

For remote path:

```
$path = 'http://example.com/img/1 silver_thumb.JPG';
$new_path = str_replace(" ", "%20", $path)
$temp_array = getimagesize($new_path);
var_dump($temp_array);
```

will give me the right array with image dimension

But equivalent method for local path doesn't work:

```
$path = '/Users/snowbound/img/1 silver_thumb.JPG';     // mac path
// $path = '/Users/snowbound/img/1silver_thumb.JPG';     // this works
$new_path = str_replace(" ", "%20", $path)
$temp_array = getimagesize($new_path);
var_dump($temp_array);
```

$temp_array is boolean false.

I've also tried surrounding $path in " quotes:

```
$new_path = "\"" . $path. "\"";
```

And escaping it with backslash:

```
$new_path = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $path);
```

Neither works.

Any idea how to use getimagesize() when local path has spaces??

Comment: `str_replace(" ", "%20", $path)` this is URL encoding, not for the local path. The quotation, if done properly, should probably work. `$path = '"/User/snowbound/img/1 silver_thumb.JPG"';` Another possible way is to escape spaces with `\ `, did not try it though.

Comment: I know @Cheery. Any idea what else I could try though besides backslash escape & surrounding path in quotes - both local file techniques...

Comment: You can read the file and use `getimagesizefromstring` in php 5.4 and above, but it is too much ) Let me check paths with spaces. Ok, Windows does not care about the space in path or filename, let me check in Linux (sorry, I do not have Mac to try). Ubuntu also does not care.

Comment: we're running 5.3.13 on production server unfortunately :(  Let me know if the Linux attempt works...

Comment: I wrote it above - tried in Ubuntu 14.04 and it also works with spaces in path and in filename. No escaping, no additional actions. On Windows it was 5.3.something, on Ubuntu - 5.4

Comment: what's the solution? did you end up using `\ `.  That solution doesn't seem to work on mac?

Comment: Nope, I used path 'as is', without any modifications. I can try in MacOSx (I have it in VirtualBox) tomorrow only. Simple line with relative and absolute paths.. `var_dump(getimagesize("test folder/image 1.jpg"));` Does it tell you that file was not found or it is not able to get info from it? May be the file is damaged or not the image?

Comment: You're right, file was corrupt.  Looks like getimagesize() handles spaces fine on local path after trying a working file.  Thanks Cheery!  If you post an answer, I'll accept it :D

Comment: `/User/…` should be `/Users/…`.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 9.10 you do not need to do anything to change the local path.  I just tried this:

```
$path = 'gfx/a test image.gif';
$temp_array = getimagesize($path);
var_dump($temp_array);
```

Results:

```
array(7) {
[0]=>
int(14)
[1]=>
int(14)
[2]=>
int(1)
[3]=>
string(22) "width="14" height="14""
["bits"]=>
int(2)
["channels"]=>
int(3)
["mime"]=>
string(9) "image/gif"
}
```

Should work the same on any other Linux version, and would be surprised if does not work on BSD/Mac